# Is there another way in which we can add a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I know of this way to add a fragment:

```
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment ); 
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add a fragment to an activity: dynamically using Java and statically using XML. 

You are already using dynamic way of adding fragment , below is statically using XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.app.myfragment"
        android:id="@+id/myfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```